# Element is not clicked by using Explicit wait, but its hovering on my element for few seconds

Tags: selenium

```
public static WebDriverWait wait;

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Dashboard")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Radiology")))
.click();
```

Radiology is not clicked but hovered for some time and then disappeared

Comment: if i use Thread.sleep(4000) its working fine but i dont want to use it

Comment: Is any exception throwed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of application loading issue,after pop-up came its taking time to align the all attributes,at this time click() mthd trying to click (its no use).

Must need to use thread.sleep() until loading issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop that checks whatever property changes to make it active instead. The code below is not specific to any language, just to give an idea.

```
itr=0
while(whateverproerty="whatever" or itr < whatevertimeoutyouwant)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1)
   itr++ 
}
```

or you could make a recursive wait function.

Using a Thread.Sleep() is not the best practice.